# How to evaluate or process if statements in data?

Tags: awk, gawk

**Background**

I wrote a bash script that pulls simple user functions from a PostgreSQL database, using awk converts pgplsql commands to SQL (like `PERFORM function()` to `SELECT function()`, removes comments `--.*`, etc.), stores the SQL commands to a file (`file.sql`) and reads and executes them in the database:

```
$ psql ... -f file.sql db
```

The functions are simple, mostly just calling other user defined functions. But how to "evaluate" or process an `IF` statement?:

```
IF $1 = 'customer1' THEN      -- THESE $1 MEANS ARGUMENT TO PGPL/SQL FUNCTION
  PERFORM subfunction1($1);   -- THAT THIS IF STATEMENT IS IN:
ELSE                          -- SELECT function('customer1'); 
  PERFORM subfunction2($1);   -- $1 = 'customer1'
END IF;
```

**Tl;dr:**

`IF`s and such are not SQL so they should be pre-evaluated using awk. It's safe to assume that above is already processed into one record with comments removed:

```
IF $1 = 'customer1' THEN PERFORM subfunction1($1); ELSE PERFORM subfunction2($1); END IF;
```

After "evaluating" above should be replaced with:

```
SELECT subfunction1('customer1');
```

if the awk to evaluate it was called:

```
$ awk -v arg1="customer1' -f program.awk file.sql
```

or if `arg1` is anything else, for example for `customer2`:

```
SELECT subfunction2('customer2');
```

**Edit**

`expr` popped into my mind first thing when I woke up:

```
$ awk -v arg="'customer1'" '
{
    gsub(/\$1/,arg)                                     # replace func arg with string
    n=split($0,a,"(IF|THEN|ELSE|ELSE?IF|END IF;)",seps) # seps to get ready for SQL CASE
    if(seps[1]=="IF") {
        # here should be while for ELSEIF
        c="expr " a[2]; c|getline r; close(c)           # use expr to solve 
        switch (r) {                                    # expr has 4 return values
        case "1":                                       # match
            print a[3]
            break
        case "0":                                       # no match
            print a[4]
            break
        default:                                        # (*) see below
            print r
            exit                                        # TODO
}   }   }' file.sql
```

(*) `expr` outputs 0,1,2 or 3:

```
$ expr 1 = 1
1
$ expr 1 = 2
0
```

However, if you omit spaces:

```
$ expr 1=1
1=1
```

Comment: Is it a question about awk, or about postgresql?

Comment: @user31264 Awk mainly, preprosessing plpgsql scripts to sql before executing them on a PostgreSQL server using `psql`. Postgres solutions are welcome also but my main interest is awk atm.

Comment: It's customary comment when downvoting.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I don't understand what you're asking. I feel like maybe you're assuming some knowledge of SQL or plpgsql or psql or whatever on our part to help clarify your requirements. If so, YMMV. Are you saying you have a script with lines like `IF $1 = 'customer1' THEN PERFORM subfunction1($1); ELSE PERFORM subfunction2($1); END IF;` written in some language and you want to write an awk script to parse that language? Isn't there some tool that already does that?

Comment: @EdMorton Pretty much, yeah. Done it in other languages the hard way but was wondering if anyone has some simple way to it in awk.

Comment: Yeah, could be. Well, I'll leave it here for a while before taking it down. Then again, it's only an `IF`.

Comment: I downvoted because I did not understand the question.

Comment: @user31264 When TL;DR you can always check the tags, sir.

Comment: @JamesBrown - even after tags I did not understand it.  Probably I am senile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without writing a full language parser, if you're looking for something cheap and cheerful then this might be a decent starting point:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ gsub(/\$1/,"\047"arg1"\047") }
match($0,/^IF\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+THEN\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+ELSE\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+END\s+IF/,a) {
    lhs = a[1]
    op  = a[2]
    rhs = a[3]
    trueAct  = (a[4] == "PERFORM" ? "SELECT" : a[4]) FS a[5]
    falseAct = (a[6] == "PERFORM" ? "SELECT" : a[6]) FS a[7]

    if (op == "=") {
        print (lhs == rhs ? trueAct : falseAct)
    }
}

$ awk -v arg1='customer1' -f tst.awk file
SELECT subfunction1('customer1');

$ awk -v arg1='bob' -f tst.awk file
SELECT subfunction2('bob');
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(). Hopefully it's easy enough to understand that you can massage as needed to handle other constructs or other variations of this construct.

Comment: Not yet, I fell asleep (: that wasn't constructive criticism, I'm at GMT+2). I'll take a better look at it at office - if I get there, it snowed last night...

Comment: Oh yeah, that is nice. But it must've been all the sSsSs that my brain rendered as zZzZz...